# adb logcat has no output

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I've been running logcat every day for the past 4 months with the following command:

```
adb logcat
```

which simply gives me all logs of the attached Android device (my phone). Since yesterday afternoon, that command suddenly doesn't give me anything anymore:

```
$ adb logcat
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

and from there nothing happens. I can start and stop all sorts of apps or run my own app, but where it used to gives a whole lot of output (most of it crap), it now doesn't output anything. I see the ADB icon in my phone:

[image]

and I tried:

- running `adb kill-server && adb start-server`
- restarting the terminal
- restarting the phone
- restarting the whole computer
- unplugging and replugging the phone

but nothing works. Yesterday morning it was still working, now it has no output anymore.

I'm on OSX 10.10 and my device is Android 4.4.4

I'm really desperate (I really need to debug an app). What can be wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Why the minus one? What's wrong with my question?

Comment: Sometimes logs stop appearing on my eclipse IDE. I just go to the Developer options inside Android settings and turn off and on the USB debugging option. After that logs start appearing again. You can give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure device connection is proper and working, try to copy file with adb.

You can use logcat on your device too. Download terminal emulator and run logcat command there. It may give you more meaningful error.

If logcat works on your device but not getting it with adb, you should read [XDA logcat tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1726238)

Edit: check your printk level

```
root@:/ # cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
7       4       1       7
(7=Current level, 4=Default level, 1=Minimum level, 7=Boot up level)
```

Comment: I tried just running `logcat` (so without the `adb ` before it) in a terminal emulator on the phone, but this also doens't give any output. Any more ideas?

Comment: Ah! I just attached another android phone, and there I do get output. So the problem is with the phone. Any ideas what could be wrong within the phone?

Comment: logcat is a binary executable file in /system/bin directory kindly look there if  its still there?

Comment: Yes, it is still there, with the following output: `-rwxr-xr-x root     shell       13592 1970-01-31 22:17 logcat`. When running `./logcat` in `/system/bin` it runs but also doesn't output anything.

Comment: Logcat records kernel level errors messages warning, some kernels disable logging in order to speed up kernel. Do you change kernel or change log settings in anywhere recently?

Comment: Ah, yes I did. I installed MultiROM manager and with that, installed Kernel 4.4 to have a kexec-hardboot patch, which supposedly allows me to have multiple ROMS on my phone (but I didn't install any additiona ROMs yet). So this is the problem? Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: if you dont use multiple ROMs dont keep the kernel which is made for it, you can change only kernel to enable log but my advice complete clean install starting from kernel will be more logical / edit: also there are this kind of tutorials too http://bitmote.com/index.php?post/2013/02/19/Enabling-Logcat-in-Custom-Android-Roms

Comment: You mean completely reinstall Android? That s***ks. Is there no easy way to enable kernel logging? Because I do want to use multiple ROMs in the future.

Comment: There is also another logger luckily which can be found 
   $ adb shell cat /proc/kmsg 
also there is dmseg too http://bamboopuppy.com/android-logging-the-linux-kernel-log/